# Table of contents title and author appear

Tags: tables

I'm having a problem with the table of contents, the title and the author appear in it and I can't manage to remove them.

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}  
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\title{Title of the Document}
\author{Me}
\maketitle

\newpage
\tableofcontents
```

Can you help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you share the code you use to create the title and the code to create the table of contents with us? You can click on "edit" on your question to add it.

Comment: Sure, here it is

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! May I ask why you use the Springer Multiauthor Volumes Class for your document? Is this class obligatory for your document or did you choose it on your own?

Comment: Yes, I need to use this template for my internship report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I compile with `\documentclass{article}` instead it looks correct. Using `llncs` causes the title to appear in the toc.

This seems to be on purpose after checking the attached manual:

> If you are the author of a single contribution you normally have no running
>   heads and no table of contents. Both are done only by the editor of the volume
>   or at the printers.

I suggest you either don't use the table of content at all or use another document class like `article`

Comment: Ok thanks, actually I must use this template for my internship report, but I might remove the table of contents then

Comment: Great! In this case your instructor probably wants the report without a ToC. If this answered your question, could you click the green checkmark on the left to mark it as "answered my question"?